# how change background color in the diffuse color mode?

Tags: 3d-view

Good day. I only need to display model color in viewport. However, when i enter into display only model color, my background becomes black. I tried to change that color in theme settings, also in editor type, but i have not found that function. Can you help me find where can i change that background color?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pass is technical, used for checking renders, not for working. If you look up for texture editing with no shading affecting, you should try Flat shading with texture display:

[image]